# Problem about the determinant of a random matrix

Tags: probability-distributions, determinant, random-matrices

I am being haunted about this problem on the value  of the determinent of this Random Matrix ever since it came into my mind last week.The problem goes like this:

> Suppose $A$ is a square matrix of order $n$ whose elements are uniformly and independently chosen from the interval $[a,b]$ where both $a$ and $b$ are positive. If $X$ is the r.v. corresponding to $\det A$ then what about the following :
>   (1)The $\min$ and $\max$ of $X$.
>   (2)The probability distribution of $X$.
>   If the case for the matrices of order $n$ seems too complicated/laborious I will be grateful for the solutions for $n=2$ and $n=3$.Am eagerly waiting !Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did you try? Did you manage to solve the case of $1\times 1$ and $2\times 2$ matrices?

Comment: when n is 1, X becomes U([a,b]) and the min and max of X are a nd b repectively.When n is 2 X can be witten as WX-YZ where W,X,Y,Z are all independent  and U([a,b]).I think the distribution of X can be derived  by cosidering the distribution of WX-YZ(but I don't know how).Further for n=2  minX=a^2-b^2 and max.X=b^2-a^2

Comment: Hint: you can study the distribution of $WX$ - this should not be difficult. Clearly, $YZ$ has the same distribution, and is independent from $WX$. Now you can study the difference $WX-YZ$: the distribution of difference should not be difficult, either.

Comment: I have not put a boounty on the question ,then how come the page shows that the question is eligible for bounty?Someone please tell me

Comment: It means that you `can` put a bounty on this question.